# Debug Angular Dart routing

Tags: dart, url-routing, angular-dart

My first few days of using Angular Dart have been delightful...

... except for the routing, which continues to give me problems. What I want is:

- `/product` to show me a list of products
- `/` to be an alias for /product (ie, /product is the default view)
- `/product/:id` to view/edit a single product

I'd tell you exactly what the problem is, except it always seems to be changing. Sometimes my view does not load at all; right now, I only get the product list, even on `/product/1128`. I've enabled logging as described in the tutorial, and the console output for `/product/1128` is:

```
listen ignoreClick=false
route path=/product/1128 startingFrom=null forceReload=false
listen on win
newHandle for [Route: null]
```

For starters, it would be helpful to know what those console messages mean. They're not very helpful to a newb like me.

Your help is much appreciated!

For your reference, this is my code (various files concatenated for your viewing pleasure):

```dart
void main() {
  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord r) { print(r.message); });

  print('main');  // my own quick-n-dirty debugging
  applicationFactory()
  .addModule(new ProductModule())
  .run();
}

class ProductModule extends Module {
  ProductModule() {
    print('ProductModule');  // more debugging
    bind(RouteInitializerFn, toValue: routeInitializer);
    bind(NgRoutingUsePushState, toValue: new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
    bind(ProductList);
    bind(ProductEdit);
  } 
}

void routeInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) {
  print('routeInitializer');
  views.configure({
    'index': ngRoute(
      path: '',
      view: 'view/product/list.html',
      mount: {
        'product': ngRoute(
          path: '/product',
          view: 'view/product/list.html',
      mount: {
        'product_edit': ngRoute(
          path: '/:id',
          view: 'view/product/edit.html'),
        }),
    })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done much with routing but maybe some hints that might help you.

There should be a `defaultRoute: true` option.
Don't add the `''` route at all, make `product` and `product_edit` the top-level routes where `product` has the `default:true` option set.

```dart
void routeInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) {
  print('routeInitializer');
  views.configure({
    'product': ngRoute(
      path: '/product',
      defaultRoute: true,
      view: 'view/product/list.html'),
      mount: {
        'product_edit': ngRoute(
          path: '/:id',
          view: 'view/product/edit.html'),
      }
  });
}
```

not tested...

Comment: I just posted almost the same answer. It seems to work! I'll delete mine in preference for yours. Follow-up question: should I be using the `mount` argument to nest `product_edit` under `product`?

Comment: You are right, I considered it but the got distracted by something.

Comment: I feel like `mount` is the "right" thing to do, but that's where all of my problems begin...